# I have a problem with the animation in Google Maps in flutters

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have designed an application using Flutter and a dart that represents the movement of the monorail on Google Map. I have 6 maps in the program, each map has an animation responsible for the movement of the monorail, and each map is linked to its own button. When I press the button, the animation of the monorail movement starts to work, but this is not logical. I want when I do By running the program before anything, this animation starts to work, so that when I open any map, I see the monorail has already moved, and I see where it is at the present time, knowing that each map is on a separate page, how do I solve this problem

I tried a lot of ways, but it didn't work for me. I'm not an expert with Flutter. It's the first time, so I don't know if it's possible or not